# how to generate unique id for table cells using map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want to set a unique id for each MenuItem, but I don't know how to do this with map() function nested in another one

```html
<table className={classes.table}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td />
      {sit.sit.map(sit => (
        <td className={classes.sitCell} align="center" key={sit}>
          {sit}
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {sit.row.map(row => (
      <tr key={row}>
        <td className={classes.rowCell} align="left">
          {row}
        </td>
        {sit.sit.map(sit => (
          <td className={classes.sit} key={(id = id + 1)}>
            <MenuItem
              id={sitId}
              onClick={handleSitClick}
              disabled={selected}
              className={classes.sit}
            />
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided code looks fine for me. You can use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or any other similar package to generate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear i think its may be help you .

```
    <table className={classes.table }>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    { 
                        sit.sit.map((sit) => (<td className={classes.sitCell} align='center' key={sit}>{sit}</td>))
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
                sit.row.map((row,index )=> (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td className={classes.rowCell} align='left'>{row}</td>
                        {   
                            sit.sit.map((sit) => (<td className={classes.sit} key={id = id+1}><MenuItem id={sitId} onClick={handleSitClick} disabled={selected} className={classes.sit}></MenuItem></td>))
                        }
                    </tr>
                ))
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

you can just add `(row,index)` like this

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to use a key which is some kind of unique id from your api response. Check your api response data structure, if it has an unique id, then use it. Else use the map array index.

**Like this**

```js
<table className={classes.table}>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            {
                sit.sit.map((sit) => (<td className={classes.sitCell} align='center' key={sit}>{sit}</td>))
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {
            sit.row.map(row => (
                <tr key={row}>
                    <td className={classes.rowCell} align='left'>{row}</td>
                    {
                        sit.sit.map((sit, index) => (<td className={classes.sit} key={index}><MenuItem id={index} onClick={handleSitClick} disabled={selected} className={classes.sit}></MenuItem></td>))
                    }
                </tr>
            ))
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```